# How to print only the non empty list results in Ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x

I would like to print only the non empty list(pog_test) in the output(JSON).  The below Register output is a result of another previous task. I have even tried using a when condition, but no luck. Is it possible to handle this in the previous task itself(have mentioned the task below) rather than creating a separate task to filter the non empty lists.

**Register Output**

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "pog_test": []
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
                "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
                "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
                "po_id": "4654646"
            }
        },
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "pog_test": [
                    {
                        "id": "782500435255624287",
                        "name": "PG-L-DE-MCC-COOLING_DMZ",
                        "networkIds": [],
                        "networkObjectIds": [
                            "12345678"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
                "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
                "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
                "po_id": "12345678"
               
            }
        }
    ],
    "skipped": false
}
```

**Task**

```
- name: Check if the POG exists for all PO.
      set_fact:
        pog_test: "{{ pog | json_query(pogquery) }}"
      vars:
        pogquery:  "[].pog[?contains(networkObjectIds, '{{ item.po_id }}')][]"
      with_items: "{{ comborgpoidcool }}"
      register: pogcheck
```

**pog**

```
[
    {
        "OrgId": "5555",
        "OrgName": "abcd",
        "pog": [
            
            {
                "id": "9546413",
                "name": "test123",
                "networkIds": [
                    "654654654"
                ],
                "networkObjectIds": [
                    "12345678"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "OrgId": "9876546",
        "OrgName": "Tdsqfsf",
        "pog": []
    },
    {
        "OrgId": "98798756",
        "OrgName": "qdqsdqdqsd",
        "pog": []
    }
]
```

**comborgpoidcool**

```
[
    {
        
        "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
        "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
        "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
        "dhcpOptions": [],
        "po_id": "4654646"
    },
    {
        "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
        "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
        "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
        "po_id": "12345678"
    }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "ansible_facts": {
                "pog_test": [
                    {
                        "id": "782500435255624287",
                        "name": "PG-L-DE-MCC-COOLING_DMZ",
                        "networkIds": [],
                        "networkObjectIds": [
                            "12345678"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ansible_loop_var": "item",
            "changed": false,
            "failed": false,
            "item": {
                "dhcpBootOptionsEnabled": false,
                "dhcpHandling": "Run a DHCP server",
                "dhcpLeaseTime": "1 day",
                "po_id": "12345678"
               
            }
        }
    ],
    "skipped": false
}
```

Comment: Print this out directly from `hostvars` with a possible mix of `dict2items`, `selectattr / rejectattr`, `map`, `items2dict`. For the exact solution, sorry but I did not understand what you want to filter out exactly. Consider crafting an [MCVE](/help/mcve) showing the actual result and the one you expect. You might not need to give your entire data for people to understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Zeitounator, Thanks for your response. I have updated the expected result as well. My only requirement is to get the output for the task without any empty list. If the jsonquery in the task is not true, then don't print in the register variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial approach was to get all the details in the pog json file which contains some value inside "pog" array . But now I have used another approach to filter the pog array whose length == 0( code as below).

```
 when:  (item.ansible_facts.pog_match | length == 0 )
```